# How to filter paths in a directed cyclic graph based on path and node attributes

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

What would be the best way to filter paths in a directed cyclic graph based on the attributes of nodes and edges? The filters can be based on finding paths that reach a destination node via nodes and paths with specific attributes.

A sample query can be like finding a path to a destination node (with a given property)
through a node and links with a given set of properties.

Since the query can be made multiple times, it would be desirable if once processed, the filtering applied could be stored and used later.
The types of queries are limited and is < 5.

The design of the graph is:

- Nodes and attributes

```
    class Node
    {
       std::string nodeName;
       std::map<std::string, Link*> forwardLinkMap;
       std::map<std::string, string> nodeProperties;
    }
Forward link map stores the name of Link and pointer to link. <br>
The node properties map have key value pairs of the property name and its value. <br>
Example of node properties: {{"population":"10000"}, {"area" : "10"},{"numberOfSupermarkets": "5"}, {"canGetChineseFood":"Yes"}, {"canGetIndianFood":"Yes"}, {hasBeach:"Yes"}}
```

- Forward links and attributes

```
    class Link
    {
      std::string linkName;
      Node* parentNode;
      Node* childNode;
      std::map<std::string, std::string> linkProperties;
    }
Example of linkProperties: {{"numberOfLanes" : "3"}, {"maxSpeed","70"} }
```

The parent node is known, and iteration starts from it.

**Example query :**

- Starting from a node with given name finding path to node with specified name and has beach through nodes where chinese food is available.
- Starting from a node and finding path to city with population < 1000 through links where minimum speed is 50 .

How can the paths be filtered, and the filtering information be stored in a way that it can be retrieved later for iteration based on the parameters provided?
The node and link classes can be modified to store the filtering information that can be used later for traversal. Main challange to me is handling case of multiple parents.

Comment: "paths with specific attributes" What does this mean? Do you mean a path that has an attribute, such as number of hops.  Or do you mean that passes through links or nodes that have the specified attributes.  Please provide the 5 queries so we can see what your question is about.

Comment: "std::map<std::string, Link*> forwardLinkMap;"  What is the key of this map?  Is it the name of the child node?  Why are the map values pointers to a link instance - you could just store the link instance in the map value.

Comment: "The node and link classes can be modified to store the filtering information"  I do not see how that would work.  You will need to write code to parse your queries, and storage for the queries, possibly as a method and attributes of a graph class.  Hard to be any more specific when you have not provided examples of your queries.

Comment: I have added examples of both attributes and sample queries. Regarding the link map that is how the current design exists and I can't do much about it but I provided  explanation about it.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to filter paths in a directed cyclic graph
> based on the attributes of nodes and edges?

This depends on the algorithm that you use to find the paths.

Assuming you are using a Dijkstra implementation with a visitor that returns a flag, then you can code the visitor to check if the path, so far, still passes the filter.  If not then the visitor can return false and the Dijsktra code will back up and explore other avenues.

You question is missing too many details to give a more detailed answer.  Please edit your question to answer the questions I posted to the comments.

> Starting from a node and finding path to city with population < 1000
> through links where minimum speed is 50 .

This query can be handled with the algorithm I describe above.

> Starting from a node with given name finding path to node with specified name and has beach through nodes where chinese food is
> available.

This query is more complicated.  You will need to find the shortest path from the start to every Chinese food node.  Then find the shortest path from every chines food node to the destination.  Finally find the shortest combination of start->chinese and chinese -> destination

Here is the main method code for the simplest query, find all paths between two nodes

```
main()
{
    // read grah and query specifications
    so758462167 spec;
    readfile(
        spec,
        "../dat/input.txt");

    // find all the paths
    auto vPaths = raven::graph::allPaths(
        spec.g,
        spec.g.find((spec.start)),
        spec.g.find((spec.dest)));

    // display the paths
    for( auto& p : vPaths )
    {
        for( auto v : spec.g.userName( p ) )
            std::cout << v << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The complete application code is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so75846217

Comment: I have attempted deploying DFS to go as far as possible and store flags specific to each query. I am struggling with cases when  a node has multiple parents regarding what flag do I return to parent nodes. Would it be advisable to traverse graph at least one time for each query and store flags for each query. Flags would be like is this node valid for query 1/2/3? Is there a way I can just iterate once and store flags specific to each query?

Comment: I assume that you want the shortest path that satisfies the filter.  So DFS is not adequate, you need Dijkstra.

Comment: No, shortest path is not required, at least one path is required, if more than one they need to be known as well. Also, I am not sure how Dijkstra would be applied with current structure without the weights being known.

Comment: If all you care about is the number of hops, set every edge weight to 1.

Comment: If you want all the paths, then find all the paths and iterate through them removing the ones that do not match the filter.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and will update. How about storing the results on each node? I have to dump the results to text file. What I have planned right now is storing query specific flags on nodes and edges and then run a visitor on graph to dump results. Any better way to do it?

Comment: Here is the C++  code to find all the paths between nodes https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths

Comment: "storing the results on each node"  This makes no sense to me.  What results, exactly, would be usefully stored in each node.

Comment: The requirement is to dump the path to text file. To meet it I am thinking of storing flags specific to each query if any particular edge/ node is part of a query's route. Then run a visitor on graph and dump all nodes and edges to file where flag is set. Since the requirement just states I have to dump the route to file, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Your plan will lose the path!  Say two vertexes have the flag for a particular query.  Are they on the same path or two different paths.  If on the same path, which is visited first.

Comment: Yes, it this is a problem.  Is there any alternative way to do it?

Comment: The usual way is to store the paths in a 2D vector. `path[x][y]' stores the index of the yth vertex on the xth path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252793/discussion-between-ravenspoint-and-stackunderflow).

Comment: I have committed code to implement the simplest query: find all paths between two nodes.  For details, look at the discussion in chat and/or the repo.